# What permissions to grant to a user to create charts in apache superset?

Tags: business-intelligence, apache-superset

These are my permissions:

[image: my permissions]

I can't figure out what other permissions to grant to users for creating charts in apache superset.

The button to create the chart is visible, but after selecting the dataset and the chart type, clicking on "create new chart", I get this error: "There was an issue fetching your recent activity: Access is Denied".

So, what permissions to grant to create charts in apache superset?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve **there was an issue fetching your recent activity: Access is Denied"**, assign the permission  below
`can recent activity on Superset`

You also require the following permissions to successfully create charts.

```
can write on Chart 
can write on Dashboard
can created slices on Superset
```